# onclick: Go Through Radio Buttons & Find Checked Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want my code to get the checked radio button value when the user clicks the save button. I have the code laid out but I am unsure how to loop through the radio buttons since they don't have a class id? Here's what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
saveButton.onclick = function() {       
    // Go through shirtColor rabio buttons to see which one is ticked
    for (var i = 0; i < shirtColor.length; i++) {
        if (.checked = true) {
            // Set shirtColor variable to selected color
            var shirtColor = .checked;

            // Only one value can be selected so we're done
            return;
        }
    }
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Shirt Color:
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="red" value="red" />
Red
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="green" value="green" />
Green
<input type="radio" name="shirtColor" id="blue" value="blue" /> 
Blue</p>
<p>
<input type="button" id="saveButton" value="Save">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Syntax error on line 10 and 12 `if (.checked = true) {`, `var shirtColor = .checked;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **plain Javascript** you could do:

```
saveButton.onclick = function() {       
    // Go through shirtColor rabio buttons to see which one is ticked
    var shirtColors = document.getElementsByName("shirtColor");
    for (var i = 0; i < shirtColors.length; i++) {
        var shirtColor = shirtColors[i];
        if (shirtColor.checked) {
            // Set shirtColor variable to selected color
            alert(shirtColor.value);

            // Only one value can be selected so we're done
            return;
        }
    }
};
```

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjsDX/).

Comment: How about some explanation of what the problem was?

Comment: @JuanMendes I appreciate your activity on this topic. The problem was that the OP did not know how to loop through all radiobuttons. His example code was much like pseudo code (hence the syntax errors, the OP already knew that). I just filled in the blanks and showed how you can loop through the radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You need to wrap this in a `<form>` to give the script some context. You don't need IDs in this case.

```
saveButton.onclick = function() {       
    var shirtColor = document.forms[0].shirtColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < shirtColor.length; i++) {
        if (shirtColor[i].checked == true) {
             return shirtColor[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The form doesn't fix the problem... you've fixed other problems that you didn't explain here

Comment: Perhaps the original poster needs to describe the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for loop to

```
var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('shirtColor');
for(var i = 0; i < cboxes.length ; i++
{
    if(cboxes[i].checked)
        shirtColor = cboxes[i];
}
```

However, if you use jquery, it would be much simpler:

```
var shirtColor = $("input[name='shirtColor']:checked").val();
```